# How can I stop my form overlaping my header

Tags: html, css

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Student Registeration</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" src="text/css" >
        <style>
    .login-box
    {
        width:280px;
        position:relative;
        top:30%;
        left:50%;
        transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        color:black;    
    }
     h1
     {
         margin: 0; 
         float:left;
         font-size:38px;
         border-bottom: 6px solid gold;
         margin-bottom: 40px;
         padding:0 0 20px;
         text-align:center;
     }
    .login-box p
     {
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
         font-size: 18px;   
    }
    .login-box input
    {
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        margin: 8px 0;
        padding:9px 0;  
    }
    .login-box input\[type="text"\], input\[type="password"\], input\[type="email"\]
     {
         border: none;
         outline: none;
         border-bottom: 1px solid gold;
         background: none;
         color:gold;
         font-size: 16px;
         width:100%;
         float:left;    
     }
    .button
         {
             font-family: century gothic;
             border: none;
             color: white;
             padding: 15px 30px;
             text-align: center;
             text-decoration: none;
             display: inline-block;
             font-size: 16px;
             margin: 10px 2px;
             cursor: pointer;
             border-radius: 19px;
             background-image: linear-gradient(to right, gold , black);
         }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            include'header.php';
        ?>
        <div class="login-box">
            <form method="post" action="authen.php" <?php echo $_SERVER\['PHP_SELF'\]; ?>>
                        <h1>Create Account</h1>
                        <p><b>Full Name : </b></p>
                                    <input type="text" class="textarea" id="fname" name=" fname" placeholder="Full Name" style="width:100%;" name="fname" pattern="\[A-Za-z \]+" required >
                            <p><b>Email :</b></p> 
                                    <input type="email" class="textarea" id="email" placeholder="Email" style="width:100%;" name="email" pattern="\[a-z0-9._%+-\]+@\[a-z0-9.-\]+\.\[a-z\]{2,}$" required>
                            <p><b>Username :</b></p>
                                    <input type="text" id="user" class="textarea" placeholder="Username" style="width:100%;" name="user" pattern="\[A-Za-z0-9\]{5,}" required>
                            <p><b>Phone :</b></p>
                                    <input type="text" id="phno" class="textarea" placeholder="Phone Number" style="width:100%;" name="phno" pattern="\[0-9\]{10}" required>
                            <p><b>Password :</b></p>
                                    <input type="password" id="pass" placeholder="Password" class="textarea" style="width:100%;" name="pass" pattern="\[A-Za-z0-9\]{6,}" required>
                            <p><b>Confirm Password :</b></p>
                                    <input type="password" id="cpass" class="textarea" placeholder="Confirm Password" style="width:100%;" name="cpass" pattern="\[A-Za-z0-9\]{6,}" required>
                            <p><b>Choose the following:</b></p>
                            <input type="radio" class="textarea" id="pfaculty" name="Faculty" value="Permanent faculty"  required >Permanent Faculty
                            <input type="radio" class="textarea" id="vfaculty" name="Faculty" value="Visiting faculty" required >Visiting Faculty
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="Button"id="btn" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

header.css

```
/*Index CSS*/
body{
    color:#008080;
    font-family:Century Gothic;
    position: relative;
}

/*Naavigation Bar*/
div{
    height:70px;
}
a{
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;  
}
#Name{
    float: left;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-top:12px;

}
.header {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
.links{
    float: right;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top:10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.links:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: #008080;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: 0.2s;
}

.header .icon {
    display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .links.icon {
        float: right;
        display: block;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .header.responsive {
        position: relative;
    }

    .header.responsive a {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }
}
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPifQ.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPifQ.png)

Here in this code I have problem that my form overlaps my header 
When I scroll down in the page it scrolls the form and overlap the header.
As I have given a picture you can see my form overlaps my header which should not happen. It should not crossover the header thats the problem.
And my radion button text is also not coming in proper format I have tried a lot things but it is not happening. So please anyone can resolve this error.[image]

Comment: Dude it is not I have just added a wrong tag of php I shoudnt have done this I know

Comment: adding a margin-top on body should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

Give `z-index` (any value you want but greater than your form) to your `header` and if there is no `position` property in your header, add `position: relative`.

Comment: can you please say which value should I give to the z-index

Comment: should I also post my header css

Comment: try to add 1111 value

Comment: where should give my z-index to login-box class

Comment: give at .header of z-index: 1111

Comment: But one more thing can tell that i have php regstration i that if pass and confir pass doesnt match it should show on the same page how would I do that

Comment: And my radio button label is also not correct bro it is not in correct formation

Comment: you can use AJAX for that and this is not related to question, so ask new question

Comment: If you like my answer or you got any help from my answer, don't forget to consider up-vote and check this answer as the best answer for you by clicking on the right arrow, thanks!